# Springboot JPA Hibernate CascadeType confusion

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, cascade

How to make a column cascade enable only for insertion not update and delete.

Here are two class. There are @ManyToOne relationship between **Qualification** and **Department**. At the time of insertion I want to insert new department with qualification. But at the time of update of qualification I don't want to update department. How can I configure that??

```
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
}


@Table(name = "qualification")
public class Qualification implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;

    private Integer passingYear;
    private String result;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, cascade = { CascadeType. ? }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Department department;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CascadeType.PERSIST` is what you are looking for. The various `CascadeType` enums essentially say, which persistence operation of EntityManager `persist`/`merge`/`remove` etc. should cascade to the objects of an association.

Comment: NOT WORKING!
I used
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade({ CascadeType.PERSIST })
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Department department;

This error is occured.

[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: coaching.administrator.classes.Department.Department; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: coaching.administrator.classes.Department.Department] with root cause

Comment: Seems like you are setting a `Department` object that has a value assigned for `id`, but it is not managed i.e. detached. If you want to refer to an existing `Department` you have to load that object via `EntityManager.find(Department.class, departmentId)` or if you know it exists, use `EntityManager.getReference(Department.class, departmentId)`